# question on Cauchy-Hadamard formula

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

I know that the radius of convergence $R$ of a power series $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kx^k$ is defined by $R:=\frac{1}{\limsup\limits_{k\to\infty}\sqrt[k]{|a_k|}}$ and it can be derived from the root test of infinite series.

However, I am wondering why we don't define the radius of convergence by $R:=\frac{1}{\limsup\limits_{k\to\infty}|a_k|}$?

If we assume that $a_k$ is bounded then for all $x$ with $|x|<\frac{1}{\limsup\limits_{k\to\infty}|a_k|}$ it follows that:
$
|a_kx|<\frac{|a_k|}{\limsup\limits_{k\to\infty}|a_k|}\leq 1$ such that $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}(|a_kx|)^k$ is a geomtric series. Further, $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\sqrt[k]{|a_k|}(|a_kx|)^k$ converges and hence $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kx^k$ converges as well.

Or is my reasoning flawed?

Comment: I don't like defining the radius of convergence by that formula. A more intuitive definition is to define $R=\sup\{|z|: \sum a_nz^n\,\text{converges}\}.$

Comment: @zhw. I really like your definition. Is it equivalent to the original?

Comment: @Nuraly It is indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple counterexample: $a_k=2$ has radius of convergence $1$, not $1/2$.

A more extreme one: $a_k=2^k$ has radius of convergence $1/2$, not $0$.

The flaw in your reasoning is in the algebra: in order to make the connection to geometric series, you should write $\sum |a_k| |x|^k = \sum \left ( |a_k|^{1/k} |x| \right )^k$. Then if $x<\frac{1}{\limsup |a_k|^{1/k}}$ then $|a_k|^{1/k} |x|<1$ for all but finitely many $k$. On the other hand if $x>\frac{1}{\limsup |a_k|^{1/k}}$ then $|a_k|^{1/k} |x|>1$ for infinitely many $k$.